# using radio button with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

Normally I can use a radio button in knockoutjs as below :

```
<input type="radio" value=1 data-bind="checked: groupvalue" /><span data-bind="text: 1"></span
```

But what if I wanted to get the values dynamically from an array..

The following does not work..

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: colors">
                        <tr><td><input type="radio" data-bind="checkedValue:$data, checked: groupvalue" /><span data-bind="text: $data"></span></td></tr>
      </tbody>
```

where colors is :

```
self.colors = ko.observableArray([
                        'Red',
                        'Green',
                        'Blue',
                        'Brown',
                        'Yellow',
                        'White',
                        'Black'
                    ]);
```

I have seen [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/FvZXj/) but am hoping for a simple answer.

Any help is sincerely appreiated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your only problem is that `groupvalue` is not defined in the model which is being iterated over, so if you look at the console you'll see an error:

> Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return colors }"
>   Message: Unable to process binding "checked: function (){return groupvalue }"
>   Message: groupvalue is not defined

And this stops further javascript working. Change that binding to something (presumably like `$root.groupvalue`) and it works just fine

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: colors">
   <tr><td><input type="radio" data-bind="checkedValue:$data, checked: $root.groupvalue" />
          <span data-bind="text: $data"></span></td></tr>
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/4h5bkw8t/

Answer (score 2):

You need to step out of the `foreach` context using `$parent` to get to `groupvalue`

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: colors">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" data-bind="checkedValue:$data, checked: $parent.groupvalue" /><span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5U3n46UFRvP8GkaA0vdM?p=preview)